# How do I loop through data in AJAX and store a particular value in it's respective td in tr

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a an issue where in I have various price changes and I need it to reflect in it's respective location. However it affects only one entry. I will post my code below, Feel free to ask about other parts of code required. I am using Codeigniter and AJAX

```
function showOffer(id_offer) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url('admin/order/getOffer'); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { o_id: id_offer },
        success: function(data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#oid').val(obj[0].oid);
            $('#select2-chosen-2').val(obj[0].offer_code);

            var product_id = obj[0].product_id;
            var free_product_id = obj[0].product_id;          
            $('.offer_price_' + product_id).val(obj[0].offer_sales_price);
            $('#freeQty_' + free_product_id).val(obj[0].quantity);
            $('#listmodal1').modal('hide');
        }
    }
});
}
```

```js
<td title="Reason for price change: <?php echo !empty($product->product_message)?' '.$product->product_message.'"':''; ?>">
    <input style="width:100%; text-align:right; padding-right:5px;"  type="text" name="paid_product_price[]" id="offer_price" class="price offer_price_<?php echo $counter; ?> paidShowMessage" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
</td>
```

It should affect all the products being fetched from database, currently it just sets the value for one tr->td

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Is this code working - url: '<?php echo base_url('admin/order/getOffer'); ?>',?

Comment: Yes it is working. The only issue here is it is just returning one value in the correct location. I have 4 products and it displays in just one product

Answer (score 0):

First of all I expect to see more separation of model and view.
Meaning: you need a service to fetch the data which will throw an event to another controller that will update the UI.
Read more about: pub sub mechanism in JavaScript.

Secondly - You can change the ajax call to return list of changed cells.

```
function showOffer(id_offer) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url('admin/order/getOffers'); ?>',
     type:'GET',
      data: {},
      success: function(data){
                 publish('dataChanged', data);
            }
      }
    });
}

subscribe('dataChanged', function(data)) {
       var offers = data.offers;

       for (int i = 0 ; i < offers.length ; i++) {
             // update cell in table
       }
});
```

Comment: What would publish do? Cos the values are fetching all of them when I `alert(data)` It is just that it only changes in one particular row when there are changes in all

Comment: publish() and subscribe() and two method related to pub / sub mechanism that throw / catch events - It will help you to separate Controller and Model - Please google for more information.